# Browser Blocking?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, session, cookies

We have a site that the client can no longer log into. IE7/8 says 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage' and Firefox says something similar. However, I have tried from multiple machines at my office and on my iPhone (3G connection, not Wifi) and can log into the site fine.

Is there some kind of browser or network setting that would prevent this from working? I tried setting IE security to very high (do not accept cookies), but I could log in even after that.

I cannot seem to reproduce this issue and wondering if I am missing something simple.

Comment: Probably a better question for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a cookies or programming issue. It sounds more like an issue with them seeing your site at all. Here are some ideas.

- They have a virus that edited their hosts file so they can't see your site.
- They're machine isn't plugged into the internet. Can they reach other sites?
- They're going to the wrong URL.

Comment: I will look into that. Currently scheduled a webmeeting to look through their machine. Unless its a new firewall or a virus, I am stumped. They can get to the login screen fine but can't get beyond that in any browser.

Comment: Sounds like a PEBKAC issue, Problem Exists Between Keyboard and Chair

Comment: I leave all possibilities on the table.